# How do I prepend a string to every link in a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps script to fetch a web page and output it back. I need to rewrite any links in the page to also load through the script.

i.e.:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow">Stackoverflow</a>
```

Would be rewritten as

```
<a href="https://script.google.com/{snip}exec?http://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
```

Where `https://script.google.com/{snip}exec?` is the URL of the script itself.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function getPage(url) {
  var options = {
    headers : {'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0'}
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  var html = response.getContentText();

  // Prepend this string to each link in the page
  var script_url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() + "?";

  // MAGIC GOES HERE

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
}
```

How do I prepend the `script_url` string to every link in the HTML page?

**Update:** While continuing trying to figure it out on my own I noticed some pages use relative URLs in their links. An answer would need to consider this and modify relative URLs to absolute URLs before prepending the script URL.

(Note: I have tagged the question with `Javascript` but the answer must be usable in a Google Apps script.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a regExp to replace what you want automatically in all the html message. If you construct a robust one this should work, but be careful there maybe some exceptions as for exemple a css url.

Here an almost working sample:

```
var script_url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() + "?url=";

function doGet(e) {
 var url = e.parameter.url;
  var options = {
    headers : {'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0'}
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  var html = response.getContentText();

  // Prepend this string to each link in the page

  // MAGIC GOES HERE
  var pattern = /href=("|')((https?:\/\/|www\.)([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([?=&\/\w\.-]*)*\/?)/igm;
  var out = html.replace(pattern,replacer);

  Logger.log(out);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(out);
}

function replacer(match, p1, p2, p3, offset, string){
//  Logger.log("replacing: "+p1+p2+" -- "+match);
  // p1 is nondigits, p2 digits, and p3 non-alphanumerics
  return("href="+p1+script_url+p2);
  return [p1, p2, p3].join(' - ');
}
```

I am only handling full URL with http or www and not relative ones, but with minor changes you can do that too.
Here some links you may want to have a look to:

[8 reg exp you should now](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149)
[Mozilla RegExp String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
[regex101](http://regex101.com/#javascript)